# Mapping array into higher-dimension - Python

Tags: python, arrays, transform, dimensions

I've to map `R^2` array `X=[x1, x2]` into `R^3` array `X'=[x1, x2, x1^2]`.

Is there any compact solution?

ADDED: My starting array is a numpy array e.g. `x = numpy.array([2, 3])`. I want to end up with another numpy array e.g. `x' = numpy.array([2, 3, 4])`.

Comment: Could you give us an exemple of your X?

Comment: If `X` is a list, you can do `[X[0], X[1], X[0]**2]`, or `X + [X[0]**2]`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please make sure your questions are clear. In this case, the concept of "array" has multiple meanings in Python. It could mean a list of lists, or an array from the `array` module, or an ndarray from the `numpy` module. The last has some shortcuts to make array modifications quicker and easier and more compact. Which kind of array are you starting with and what kind of array do you want as a result? It would be best to show an example array, building it with Python code.

Comment: @RoryDaulton it sounds like they mean something to do with linear algebra arrays

Comment: Thank you, my staring array is a `numpy` array e.g. `x = numpy.array([2, 3])`, I want another `numpy` array e.g. `x' = numpy.array([2, 3, 4])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the case where your array is a numpy array with shape `(2,)`, one way to add the additional member is

```
xx = numpy.append(x, x[0]**2)
```

Unfortunately, if you try something like `x + [x[0]**2]` numpy will add the elements together rather than append the new element. If you try something like `[x[0], x[1], x[0]**2]` you end up with a list rather than a numpy array.